# How to redirect a person to a link from an app

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using firebase remote config to pop-up a dialog...

**If the user clicks on UPDATE then I want him to be directed to a link in new browser tab**

This is the pic of remote config so whenever i change the update_url value and deploy it the user should be directed to that link when he clicks on UPDATE

[image: this is the pic of remote config]

Currently I use this code when the user clicks on UPDATE

```
  @Override
public void onUpdateCheckListener(final String urlApp) {

    //create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("New Version Available")
            .setMessage("Please update to latest version to have new great Experiences and Features")
            .setPositiveButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + urlApp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();

                }
            }).create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

put this code on your update button click and replace url with your url.

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
   url = "http://" + url;


Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: actually m changing the parameters from firebase config so the urlapp is the column in which i will put a random link so when the users clicks on update it should redirect it to browser